# How does `.get("key")` on a `Option[Map[String,String]]` work

Tags: scala

When I create an `Option[Map[String,String]]` like this

```
scala> val x = Some(Map("foo" -> "bar"))
x: Some[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Some(Map(foo -> bar))
```

Why does this call work:

```
scala> x.get("foo")
res0: String = bar
```

Since `x` is of instance `Option` and there is no method `get` that accepts parameters on the `case class Some` and that class is final, this should not work. The IDE is not giving any hints, why this works.

Comment: It's calling the apply method on Map

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Option` has a `get` method that has no parameter list. You call it by just using the name `get` without an argument list:

```
scala> val x = Some(Map("foo" -> "bar"))
x: Some[scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String]] = Some(Map(foo -> bar))

scala> x.get  // Note: no arguments
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(foo -> bar)
```

What you get back is, obviously, the `Map`.

The `("foo")` after `get` is applied to the `Map`. Note that this is shortcut syntax for calling the `apply` method on the `Map`. So, `x.get("foo")` is equivalent to `x.get.apply("foo")`.

```
scala> x.get("foo")  // Shortcut syntax
res2: String = bar

scala> x.get.apply("foo")  // For this
res3: String = bar
```